# python AES Encrypt

Tags: python, django, aes

I am new in python/django. I want to use AES Encryption.
after search I found some libraries like this: https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/1291836
but I could not use them because of I have IV but this dont have IV code.
I have sample code in c#. any one may help me to convert this code to python code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
namespace AESUtility {
 public class AES {
  string AES_Key = string.Empty;
  string AES_IV = string.Empty;
  public AES(string AES_Key, string AES_IV) {
   this.AES_Key = AES_Key;
   this.AES_IV = AES_IV;
  }
  public bool Encrypt(String Input, out string encryptedString) {
   try {
    var aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 256;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(this.AES_Key);
    aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(this.AES_IV);
    var encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    byte[] xBuff = null;
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
     using(var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
      byte[] xXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input);
      cs.Write(xXml, 0, xXml.Length);
     }
     xBuff = ms.ToArray();
    }
    encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(xBuff);
    return true;
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    encryptedString = string.Empty;
    return false;
   }
  }
  public bool Decrypt(String Input, out string decodedString) {
   try {
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 256;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(this.AES_Key);
    aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(this.AES_IV);
    var decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] xBuff = null;
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
     using(var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
      byte[] xXml = Convert.FromBase64String(Input);
      cs.Write(xXml, 0, xXml.Length);
     }
     xBuff = ms.ToArray();
    }
    decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xBuff);
    return true;
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    decodedString = string.Empty;
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you have a particular problem converting the code, then please update the question.

Comment: this c# code is just a sample of what I want. I dont need to some one covert it to python.

Comment: you can use http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/, it has support for setting own IV. For example:  http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html

Comment: how did you write above c# code with python at last ?! @vahidmehrjooei

Comment: there was no way to have block size 256 in pycrypto library, I used php code in python!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2022**

pycrypto is now probably unmaintained. Latest release was in Oct 2013 (see https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/#history)

In modern projects, use [pycryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) instead. The official documentation gives example of AES encryption: https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/examples.html#encrypt-data-with-aes

**Original answer:**

Here is an example of AES encryption using well known [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) library:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> message = "The answer is no"
>>> ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
>>> ciphertext
'\xd6\x83\x8dd!VT\x92\xaa`A\x05\xe0\x9b\x8b\xf1'
>>> obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
'The answer is no'
```

Comment: Message here is chosen exactly as 16 bytes. Incase if the message size is not a multiple of 16, it has to be made so with the help of padding. AES is block cipher after all.

Answer (score 2):

AES 256 in OFB mode:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import new as Random
from hashlib import sha256
from base64 import b64encode,b64decode

class AESCipher:
  def __init__(self,data,key):
    self.block_size = 16
    self.data = data
    self.key = sha256(key.encode()).digest()[:32]
    self.pad = lambda s: s + (self.block_size - len(s) % self.block_size) * chr (self.block_size - len(s) % self.block_size)
    self.unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]

  def encrypt(self):
    plain_text = self.pad(self.data)
    iv = Random().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(self.key,AES.MODE_OFB,iv)
    return b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(plain_text.encode())).decode()

  def decrypt(self):
    cipher_text = b64decode(self.data.encode())
    iv = cipher_text[:self.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(self.key,AES.MODE_OFB,iv)
    return self.unpad(cipher.decrypt(cipher_text[self.block_size:])).decode()
```

Usage:

`AESCipher("data to encrypt","key to use").encrypt()`

`AESCipher("encrypted data","key to use").decrypt()`